# Need some help debugging a simple color changer

Tags: javascript

I am making a color switcher for a website (dark mode / light mode)
and I'm having issues storing the value in a cookie and having it work out alright. I'm sure I'm making some very basic mistakes here but I couldn't find out why this isn't working and I do want to understand and also know if there's just a way simpler way of doing this.

HTML

```
<div class="buttonSwitch">
    <input id="lightMode" type="button" value="LIGHT MODE">
    <input id="darkMode" type="button" value="DARK MODE">
</div>
```

JS

```
localStorage.setItem('color', '0');
const colorChecker = function() {
    if (localStorage.color.length < 2) {
        document.body.style.color = 'whitesmoke';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#1b1b1f';
    }
    else if (localStorage.color.length > 2) {
        document.body.style.color = '#1b1b1f';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'whitesmoke';
   }
}

window.onload = colorChecker();
document.getElementById('lightMode').onclick = function thisLight() {
    localStorage.color = localStorage.color + '1';
    colorChecker();
}

document.getElementById('darkMode').onclick = function thisDark() {
    let x = localStorage.color;
    x.slice(0, -1);
    colorChecker();
}
```

Comment: "couldnt find out why this isnt working " -- we don't know what you want it to do.  Please explain what you want and what you're seeing instead (edit the question).

Comment: You mentioned cookies, but you're using `localStorage`.

Comment: Ack, I put an answer but I bet it wasn't the issue - are you by any chance using a local HTML file to test this which isn't hosted on a server or localhost? Cause localStorage won't work with an HTML file which isnt' being served.

Comment: I am using it on a html file not a localhost. Thanks for this info as well i appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Your `window.onload = colorChecker();` runs the *result* of `colorChecker` when the window's loaded. Pass a reference rather than a call

```
window.onload = colorChecker;
```

Also, when you're setting the window colour to dark, you obtain a reference to the value and slice it - this doesn't modify the value stored in `localStorage`. You need to use `setItem` again:

```
x.slice(0, -1);
localStorage.setItem('color', x);
```

And once more in the light button handler:

```
localStorage.setItem(localStorage.getItem('color') + '1');
```

Think about how this is meant to work - I'd suggest using a `0` or `1` rather than using string lengths, as it's easier to work out what's going on. Here's the code updated to do that:

```
localStorage.setItem('color', '0');
const colorChecker = function() {
    if (+localStorage.getItem('color') == '0') {
        document.body.style.color = 'whitesmoke';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#1b1b1f';
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem('color') == '1') {
        document.body.style.color = '#1b1b1f';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'whitesmoke';
   }
}

window.onload = colorChecker;

document.getElementById('lightMode').onclick = function thisLight() {
    localStorage.setItem('color', '1');
    colorChecker();
}

document.getElementById('darkMode').onclick = function thisDark() {
    localStorage.setItem('color', '0');
    colorChecker();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i really appreciate you taking the time to help me on this. I also had one more question. If the user sets it to dark mode will this data still be stored in the localStorage or would i have to create a cookie like document.cookie = ' ';?

Comment: It'll be stored in local storage @ChristopherLopez - it's kind of like a cookie, so it'll be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have trouble storing a boolean value in local storage? You can use `JSON.parse()` to read it:

```
// Store `whiteModeOn` setting, creating item if necessary (e.g. first visit)
if (localStorage.getItem("whiteModeOn") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("whiteModeOn", true);
}

function colorChecker() {
    /* Local storage may use strings, so we decode the bool with JSON.parse(),
       so both true or "true" will be true. */
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.whiteModeOn)) {
        /*  CSS classes would be better here, of course */
        document.body.style.color = '#1b1b1f';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'whitesmoke';
    } else {
        document.body.style.color = 'whitesmoke';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#1b1b1f';
    }
}

window.onload = colorChecker; /* just reference the function */
document.getElementById('lightMode').onclick = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('whiteModeOn', true);
    colorChecker();
} 
document.getElementById('darkMode').onclick = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('whiteModeOn', false);
    colorChecker();
}
```

Comment: wow, yes i did have trouble storing it as a boolean so kind of made a messy workaround, thanks for this code!